# Calculate sum $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} (-1)^{n-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, taylor-expansion

I need to calculate next sum $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} (-1)^{n-k}$$

Origin of this problem is expansion of a function $$f(x) = cosh(x) \cdot cos(x)$$ in a Taylor series.

I've tried too present this function in form:  $$f(x) = \frac{(e^x + e^{-x})}{2} \cdot \frac{(e^{ix} + e^{-ix})}{2}$$
and use expansion of exp and got this sum after some simplifications.

Also I've tried to do this using next formula and got this sum too:
$$g(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}(x-a)^n$$
$$h(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}d_{n}(x-a)^n$$ 
$$g(x)\cdot h(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}c_{k} d_{n-k})\right)(x-a)^n$$

As I understand right answer is $$f(x) = cosh(x) \cdot cos(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n 2^{2n} \frac{x^{4n}}{(4n)!}$$
and 
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} (-1)^{n-k} = (-1)^{n/2} 2^{n}$$

but I dont know, how to get it

Comment: That last equality can't be right, because $(-1)^{n}\frac{2^{2n}}{(4n)!}$ isn't an integer.

Comment: Hint: This sum is the real part of $$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}\,i^k=(1+i)^{2n}=(2i)^n$$

Comment: or so $$2^n \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your subquestion, you have $a=0$ and $c_k=d_k=0$ if $k$ is odd and $c_{2k}=\frac{1}{(2k)!}$ and $d_{2k}=\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}$.

So your coefficients $e_{n}$ are zero when $n$ is odd, and:

$$e_{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} c_{2k}d_{2n-2k} =\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(2k)!(2n-2k)!}=\frac{1}{(2n)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{2n}{2k}$$

So, given the answer you want, you need to show:

$$(2n)!e_{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{2n}{2k}=\begin{cases}0&n\text{ odd}\\
(-1)^{n/2}2^{n}&n\text{ even}\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

That's because your condition above says $e_{2n}=0$ when $n$ odd, and $(4n)!e_{4n}=(-1)^n2^{2n}.$

Comment: yeah, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}{2n\choose 2k}$$
is the real part of $(1+i)^{2n}$ where $i^2=-1$ (expand that by the
binomial theorem).